# How to properly check the result of copying file while using std::fstream and std::filebuf

Tags: c++, fstream, filebuf

I would like to use widely known code snippet to copy file:

```
std::ifstream src("in");
std::ofstream dest("out");

dest << src.rdbuf();
```

The question is: how to properly check if copying succeded?

I thought that checking the value of (src && dest) is ok, but it fails in case of empty source file.

Comment: Well, you could ensure the source file isn't empty first. I know this sounds like an ugly specialcase, but then again, an empty file is kinda special.